# Как назвать жителя города Минеральные Воды?

Tags: этнохороним

Как назвать жителя города Минеральные Воды? 
А жительницу?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В словаре названий жителей РСФСР — минераловодчанин, минераловодчанка; минераловодец, минераловодка.

Answer (score 1):

Минводчанин, минводчанка. От привычных всем Минвод.

Comment: И отсебятина: кавминводчане.

Answer (score 1):

Я живу там! Мужчина - "минераловодец", женщина - "минераловодка", жители города - "минераловодчане".

Comment: Очень может быть, что живете. Мне только интересно, кроме того, что Вы там живете есть какие-то аргументы? Прежде всего странно, что форма на "-ец" пораждает множественное с другим суффиксом. И с женщиной уточните, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

минераловодка - это класс!
А как жители сами себя называют?
Например, жители города Осташков называют себя не "осташковцы", как следовало бы ожидать, а "осташи".

может, и у минераловодчан есть своё название?

Answer (score 0):

Этнохороним:
минераловодчане, минераловодчанин

(Вики)

Я думаю, вариант этот благозвучнее другого (минераловодка!), пусть даже и словарем предлагаемого.